# How to do a multi check for null values after Dart null safety?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

```dart
int? foo, bar, baz;
bool get allGood => foo != null && bar != null && baz != null;

void f1() {
  if (allGood) {
    print('${foo.abs()} ${bar.abs()} ${baz.abs()}}'); // Error
  }
}

void f2() {
  if (allGood) {
    print('${foo.ceil()} ${bar.ceil()} ${baz.ceil()}}'); // Error
  }
}
```

I had been using this pattern in my project before null safety but currently it is causing an error. I know by the time `if` condition is checked I can use `variable!.function()` but is there any better way of writing it which I am not aware of.

Comment: @Dude Thanks but `?.` and `!.` are basically the same thing after `null` checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd do is to inline the check:

```dart
void f1() {
  var foo = this.foo, bar = this.bar, baz = this.baz;
  if (foo != null && bar != null && baz != null) {
    print('${foo.abs()} ${bar.abs()} ${baz.abs()}}');
  }
}
```

If I *really* want to reuse the test code, I'd do something like:

```dart
void ifAllGood(void Function(int, int, int) action) {
  var foo = this.foo, bar = this.bar, baz = this.baz;
  if (foo != null && bar != null && baz != null) {
    action(foo, bar, baz);
  }
}
void f1() {
  ifAllGood((foo, bar, baz) {
    print('${foo.abs()} ${bar.abs()} ${baz.abs()}}');
  });
}
void f1() {
  ifAllGood((foo, bar, baz) {
    print('${foo.ceil()} ${bar.ceil()} ${baz.ceil()}}');
  });
}
```

It's very unlikely to be worth that extra complexity.

Comment: I already knew the first part but thanks for out of the box thinking in second part. I know it is less likely to be used as a solution but it was nice!